# Showing expand image in twitter by default while sharing url using meta tag

Tags: twitter, meta-tags

[image]

**Bitbucket showing image by default like that i want to show image before view photo.**

Comment: You want to show image when you share you url?

Comment: i can able to see photo only after clicking view photo , but i want to show image without clicking view photo like atlassian bitbucket

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#opengraph https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/ May be it will help.

Comment: @AsimKT already am getting all content while post url in twitter, but it showing after view photo click... see difference between **bigfday** and **bitbucket** eventhough it has view button at the bottom it showing preview image

Comment: What library are you using? What Language? add some code. If you ask a general question, then this is not a right place.

Comment: no code is need here.. while posting url in twitter it should take image, description, title  from  meta tag of that url